# iOS 9 specific linker error with respect to WebKit.framework

Tags: webkit, linker-errors, ios9.3

I am receiving the following linker error on iOS 9 and above. I am stuck with this issue for quite sometime. Any help would be appreciable.

```
ld: file not found: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKitLegacy.framework/WebKitLegacy for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: The error message says "use -v to see invocation". Were you able to do so? If yes, what was the result? With that information, maybe we can help you.

Comment: Can you please guide how to do that? Do I have to execute the project thru terminal?

Comment: How are you invoking the loader? Are you starting it from the command line, or from an IDE? If it's from the command line, you probably should just use a "-v" option in the command. If it's from the IDE, there's hopefully a setting somewhere. "-v" probably means "verbose" in this context.

Comment: I am currently running the app from IDE. Let me try on terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue my removing WebKit.framework from the project's file system and again adding it only thru Build phases.